# Title Tag is not showing special characters

Tags: apache, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, title

I wanted to add some Special Characters (ä ö ü - for example) to my Title-Tag.

My HTML Header looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de-DE">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>jüst ä test ... ök !</title>
  (... several CSS/JS Files ...)
</head>
```

my apache file /etc/apache2/conf.d/charset is the following :

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

When I open my website and check Firebug I get the following Header Feedback

```
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

so what am I missing here ?

Before you ask here some more information which might be useful :

```
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    gzip
Server  Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Vary    Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.12
```

Comment: *We* are missing information about a) what actually happens (your browser explodes? “ä” shows as “☺”? something else?) and b) what the actual encoding of the HTML document is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is, however special characters are showing for me in:

- Chrome 35.0.1916.153 m
- Firefox 28.0
- IE 11

Tested on IIS8 (Server 2012) and Apache/2.4.7 (Win32)

**EDIT**

Turns out the problem was based on the file editor, the default save setting needs to be set to UTF-8.

Comment: The problem must be server related then with the same browser : User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0 - i can view OTHER websites with those special characters in the title tag, but somehow not mine

Comment: I can post my server info

Comment: what happens if you put &#196; at the begging of your title tag?

Comment: For sure thats working and gives me an Ä at the beginning of my title

Comment: So just curious, what are you using to edit this file?

Comment: PSPAD - you thinkg that could be a problem ? Let me try to use "vi" on my shell then to change my title - *edit* well I liked the idea that the editor COULD be the problem, sadly it wasn't the error prone

Comment: What if I send you my file and you confirm that it doesn't work as well.  It is up to the editor to encode the files properly. - https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-aJn0hKdnCsTVVYSUFTSXBDSTQ

Comment: ok I am curious now - as I clicked on your file I saw no ä/ö/ü just <?> but I just downloaded it was it was and uploaded it via SCP and it works.

Comment: Yeah, so I think it is based on the file encoding by your editor.  Your editor must not be saving them in UTF-8 format. For example, in windows notepad, the default file save is ANSI, which produces the <?> that you saw.

Comment: Hah ... well I uninstalled PSPad - reinstalled it - set UTF-8 again and say what ? It's working. Thanks Jim you saved me a hell of time.

Comment: Hey can you mark this as answered so people know the issue has been resolved. Thanks.